# SQL Payment Duplication Detection

Tags: sql, duplicates, payment, invoice

Dealing with a very large database of a firm - the database houses a record of all the payments to and from the firm to the suppliers. I want to find out whether duplicate/ triplicate payments have been made to the suppliers over a certain period of time. The only way I can interact with the database is by using a plugin via Excel and some SQL coding. Any suggestions on how I may go about doing this?

Completion of this task isn't urgent. Just want to start somewhere and hopefully develop this question over time.

Comment: Ok. So what is your question? How to do sql coding?

Comment: Yea what are you asking for?  Pull all the data into excel and then use excel to find the duplicates

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Slightly but not completely. I don't know how I should be detecting the duplication to begin with. What should I do to find out whether a double or triple payment has been made?

Comment: Count them? Is this serious?

Comment: How should we know, if you can give us the structure of the data we could be able to help

Comment: It's a REALLY big database and I'm only able to pull little portions of data out at a time before I get timed-out.

Comment: So index the tables, increase the time-out or just write better queries. No-one can help you here because you've not shared anything about the system you're working against.

Comment: The database is called Agresso and I'm using a plugin called Agresso Excelerator inside Excel to query that database.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT suppliername,date, COUNT(*) AS Nb
FROM yourtable
where date >= 'put your date'
GROUP BY suppliername,date
HAVING ( COUNT(*) > 1 )
```